# Why is $("#tags").autocomplete not working with data from PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

```
  <script>
  <?php
    mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("Project_Part1")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sqlActivity = "SELECT aname FROM Activity";
    $resultActivity=mysql_query($sqlActivity);
    $aname = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultActivity)) {
      $aname[] = $row;
   }    
  ?>
  $(function() {
        var availableTags =[ "<?php echo implode('","',$aname);?>" ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>
```

Not sure why
`var availableTags =[ "<?php echo implode('","',$aname);?>" ];`
 is not working for the autocomplete. 
When I use `var availableTags = [ "Rock climbing","Fishing","Kayaking","Underwater bungee jumping" ];` It is fine.

I'm new on PHP. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You're mixing JavaScript and PHP - the former is a client-side language, while the latter is server-side.

Comment: The code what you pasted cannot be valid PHP code.

Comment: PHP can contain and even start with html, so it's possible for a PHP file to start with `<script>`. For instance a file `customscripts.php` can have code that looks like `<script><?= $controller->generateCustomScripts();?></script>`. Nevertheles, you're right that in this case it wasn't probably intended.

Comment: I think <script> is a typo. And your problem is $connection. Do you have a link to your database? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
If you inspect the page you will understand what $connection variable is.

Comment: I do have that part, the problem is on "var availableTags". If I use "var availableTags = [ "Rock climbing","Fishing","Kayaking","Underwater bungee jumping" ];", it is fine.

Comment: When you view the source of the page when you run it in the browser, what does it show you for var `availableTags =[]` ?

Comment: @Jason: How to print it?

Comment: @user3602167 Open the page in your browser...Right Click...View Source (or something like that depending on your OS/Browser)  That will give you the rendered HTML/JavaScript where you can see if there are any errors caused by PHP output

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
    $DBi   = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password, $database);
    $aname = array();

    $sqlActivity = "SELECT `aname` FROM `Activity`";
    $resultActivity = mysqli_query($DBi, $sqlActivity);   //Dump mysql_query for 
                                                          //mysqli_query and don't 
                                                          //forget the connection bit
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultActivity)) {
        $aname[] = $row;
    };    
?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags =[ "<?php echo implode('","',$aname);?>" ];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>
```

It looks like you are missing `<?php` right after your `<script>` tag.  I moved the PHP SQL bit outside of your `<script>` tag (which should not matter but does help to keep things a little easier to read in my mind)

*While you are at it, stop using mysql_ and switch over to mysqli_ functions as the former are deprecated*

Comment: I do have the connection part. I didn't put it here since stackoverflow showed me an alert said I have too many codes than description. The problem is on "var availableTags"

Comment: <?php
  mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("Project_Part1")or die("cannot select DB");
  $sqlActivity = "SELECT aname FROM Activity";
  $resultActivity=mysqli_query($sqlActivity);
  $aname = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultActivity)) {
    $aname[] = $row;
 }    
?> This is my whole php part